# Is SqlGeometry.STUnion method thread safe?

Tags: c#, multithreading, sqlgeometry

Is SqlGeometry.STUnion method thread safe in .Net?
[MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeometry.stunion.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decompiled body from sql 11.0 assembly using JustDecompile:

```
    [SqlMethod(IsDeterministic=true, IsPrecise=false)]
    public SqlGeometry STUnion(SqlGeometry other)
    {
        if (this.IsNull || other == null || other.IsNull || this.Srid != other.Srid)
        {
            return SqlGeometry.Null;
        }
        this.ThrowIfInvalid();
        other.ThrowIfInvalid();
        return SqlGeometry.Construct(GLNativeMethods.Union(this.GeoData, other.GeoData), this.Srid);
    }
```

where `SqlGeography.Construct` and `GLNativeMethods.GeodeticUnion` are static methods, while others can't be deadlocked anywhere. None of the methods used is modifying the calling object, so yes - it's thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

How can it not be? SqlGeometry seems to be immutable - so the input of 2 immutable classes should be a determined output.

Comment: I don't understand very well. I have more than 100 thousand items to make union and it is very slow in one cycle.